# Remove data from string property in a json

Tags: javascript, json

Given the following log object:

```
{
  "message": "login: error {\"error\":{\"message\":\"Network Error\",\"name\":\"Error\",\"stack\":\"Error: Network Error\\n    at something (somewhere)\\n    at something (somewhere)\",\"config\":{\"url\":\"/a/place\",\"method\":\"get\",\"headers\":{\"Accept\":\"application/json, text/plain, */*\",\"Authorization\":\"bla blablabla\",\"X-Amzn-Trace-Id\":\"yadiyadiyadi\"},\"baseURL\":\"verygoodplace"}}}",
  "level": "warning",
  "sessionId": "blablabla"
}
```

How can I remove the `message.headers.Authorization` entry completely?
Since it appears inside a string, I can't (directly) use lodash unset, and I somehow need to alter the string.

Comment: What language do you use?

Comment: @Serge javascript

Comment: I would recommend to tweak the `message` string a little until it can be parsed with `JSON.parse()`. You will then get a JS object that is easy to manipulate. And then you can use use `JSON.stringify()` to convert that back to a similar string as what you started with. It may seem like a lot of steps, but doing this kind of string manipulation directly is an even bigger pain in the you-know-where.

Comment: @PeterB What I should tweak so I can parse it? Should I just unescape it?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to clean `message` a bit so it can be parsed with `JSON.parse()`. It looks like discarding text before the first **`{`** will be all that's needed.

Parsing will create a JS object that is easy to manipulate, after which you can use `JSON.stringify()` to convert it back to a similar string as what you started with.

It may seem like a lot of steps, but doing this kind of string manipulation directly could be an even bigger pain in the you-know-where.

**Working demo:**

```js
const logObj = {
  "message": "login: error {\"error\":{\"message\":\"Network Error\",\"name\":\"Error\",\"stack\":\"Error: Network Error\\n    at something (somewhere)\\n    at something (somewhere)\",\"config\":{\"url\":\"/a/place\",\"method\":\"get\",\"headers\":{\"Accept\":\"application/json, text/plain, */*\",\"Authorization\":\"bla blablabla\",\"X-Amzn-Trace-Id\":\"yadiyadiyadi\"},\"baseURL\":\"verygoodplace\"}}}",
  "level": "warning",
  "sessionId": "blablabla"
}

const index = logObj.message.indexOf("{");
const jsonText = logObj.message.substring(index);
const parsed = JSON.parse(jsonText);

delete parsed.error.config.headers.Authorization;   // remove unwanted node

console.log("The cleaned message:");
console.log(JSON.stringify(parsed, undefined, 2));  // print with indentation

const prefix = logObj.message.substring(0, index);
logObj.message = prefix + JSON.stringify(parsed);

console.log("The updated logObj:");
console.log(JSON.stringify(logObj, undefined, 2));  // print with indentation
```

*Note* - to make this work I had to change `verygoodplace"` to `verygoodplace\"`, it looks like you made an error when preparing the `log object` for use in the question.

Comment: Wow! Thank you very much! This is exactly was I was looking for!

I'm having problems running this with this [message](https://pastebin.com/raw/yGVPZN10), getting Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected number in JSON at position 779. But I don't see any numbers in that position, so I'm not sure what went wrong there.

Comment: In that other message there seems to be garbage at the end of the message string: `- C ID: 124asf-12412rasf-12412qsf-124asfasf_430` . You'll have to remove it in a similar way, if you want to keep using the `JSON.parse` approach. Try using `const index2 = jsonText.lastIndexOf("}")` followed by `const jsonText2 = jsonText.subString(0, index2)` or something of that nature (might have to use index2 + or - 1), and create `parsed` from that.